# Navigate into canvas, like google maps

Tags: html, canvas

So, i have a really big canvas (width can be exceed 10000px).

I'm looking for a way to navigate into this canvas, like we navigate into google maps.

I should be able to navigate the canvas by clicking the mouse and dragging the canvas with maybe a zoom option.

Do you know an easy way to do that ?

I can create this system but if i can gain some times... Thanks !

Comment: What's the point of drawing 10000px canvas if your screen is most likely x-times smaller?

Comment: I'm working on a map, just like a google map ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question is too old but it can be useful for someone in the future.

I don't suggest you to use such a big canvas at raw. Use canvas at perfect size for your window and just redraw it as needed like google maps do.

There is also a tiny package [canv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canv) which let you avoid all that problems related to resizing and navigating. You can use it as usual canvas but with some great utilities like pan, zoom, selecting objects, rotating, etc. Just check [the demo](https://alick09.github.io/canv/) out. It's very simple and easy to get started.